# How to get the latest closing price in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to get the latest closing price in pinescript. I thought this is a simple thing to do, yet I face difficulty.

I tried `close` but this returns the closing price of the bar selected by the mouse. What I want is the closing price of the last bar in the price history.

I am using pinescript v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var float my_close = 0.
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    my_close := close

plot(my_close)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Upvoted. It is not exactly what I want. I asked another follow-up question clarifying what I want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74076838/how-to-get-the-latest-closing-price-in-pinescript